# Converting Coordinates from wgs84 to UTM?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, coordinates, global-mapper

I have a geographical (longitude/Latitude) coordinates and 
i want to Convert it to UTM.

11° 13' 47.034 N , 125° 1' 30.492" E

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Online converters [Geographic Tools: Coordinate Conversion / Datum Transformation](http://www.synnatschke.de/geo-tools/coordinate-converter.php) or [Convert Geographic Units](http://www.rcn.montana.edu/resources/converter.aspx) gave the following answer: `Northing 1242142.4`, `Easting 721103.5`, `Zone 51`. Looks like Daniel Z. Romualdez Airport in the Philippines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to know what UTM zone you are in. Follow the directions here (link in Step 2) to figure that out: https://agribotix.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000855414-How-do-I-convert-my-EPSG-4326-data-to-my-UTM-zone-

If you are using the ArcGIS Desktop interface, you can use the "Projection" tool (Data Management > Projections and Transformations > Project).

If you are coding it in Python, the syntax is here: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/project.htm